# Mongodb Update is not working for nested object array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to push element inside the nested object. I am not getting any error but record is not updating.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa589b31b79fbe3312d3a1b"), 
    "settings" : {
        "clientSetting" : [
            "Hello1",
             "Hello2",
        ], 
        "adminSetting" : [
            "Hello1",
             "Hello2",
        ], 
    }
}
```

Modal declarations:-

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const settingSchema = new Schema(
  {
    settings: {
      clientSetting: [
        { type: String },
      ],
      adminSetting: [
        { type: String },
      ],
    },
  },
  { collection: 'mySettings' },
);

export default mongoose.model('MySetting', settingSchema, 'mySettings');
```

Here is what I tired

```
export const update = (req, res) => {

    MySetting.find((err, globalSettings) => {
     MySetting.update(
         { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(globalSettings[0]._id) },
         { $push: { 'settings.$.clientSetting': { type: req.body.value } } },);
      });
}
```

here I want to push { type: req.body.value } into clientSetting.

Comment: `{ $push: { 'settings.clientSetting': { type: req.body.value } } }` Since `settings` is not an "array" and you don't need a "positional match".

Comment: I tried with this { $push: { 'settings.clientSetting': { type: req.body.value } but didn't working!! @NeilLunn

Comment: Nope that's the correct one. Please don't ever say "I tried this" to anything that is not actually stated in your question. Go and "really do it" rather than comment "i tried" 2 seconds after someone told you better.

Comment: `{ $push: { 'settings.clientSetting':  req.body.value } }` of course being the correction. `type` is the mongoose schema type and not an actual property. The mismatch would cause this to be rejected